# Detect the presence of non stereochemically annotated atoms in mol files

Tags: stereochemistry, software

I'm facing a problem now and I don't know where to start from. I'm treating databases in which there are mol-files that have stereo-chemical carbons, which, sometime, are not annotated as being R/S or Z/E in the stereochemistry column.

I would like to be capable of finding all asymmetric carbons to check if the stereochemical center is annotated or not. Does anyone knows of a software, a library or elegant piece of code to figure out this problem. I'm working with RDkit (Python) and I can access to chemaxon if needed.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

With the latest rdkit, version **2022.9.4**, it is possible to obtain the information about all the unassigned chiral carbons from a MOL file, using the `rdkit.Chem.FindMolChiralCenters` function along with the argument `includeUnassigned` set to **`True`**.

A sample MOL that I use for demonstration: `2-methylbutan-1-ol.mol`

```
Actelion Java MolfileCreator 1.0

  6  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    3.4641   -0.5000   -0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.5981   -0.0000   -0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.7321   -0.5000   -0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.7321   -1.5000   -0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8660   -0.0000   -0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -0.5000   -0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  1  1  0  0  0  0
  3  2  1  0  0  0  0
  4  3  1  0  0  0  0
  5  3  1  0  0  0  0
  6  5  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
```

A sample code is shown below:

```
from rdkit.Chem import rdmolfiles, FindMolChiralCenters
mol=rdmolfiles.MolFromMolFile('2-methylbutan-1-ol.mol')
chiral_carbon_info = FindMolChiralCenters(mol, includeUnassigned=True)

print(chiral_carbon_info)
# >> [(2, '?')]
```

The output means there is a chiral carbon whose atom id is 2 and the question mark means that the chirality configuration is not defined.

**PS:**

The sample MOL file was created using this [website](http://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/Generate_molfiles/index.html), which allows you to create a MOL file either from SMILES string or manually drawing the various atoms in the molecule.